# I had problem with tkinter button command function

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter, command

I made Facebook script when I run that he is giving me error hi is not defined
he is not starting when I disable Tkinter and start with power shell he is working correctly please help me! I'm using python 3 here is my error screenshot I made this GUI with Tkinter when I run That he is giving me an error and not starting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U3v4.png)

**PYTHON CODE**

```
import pyautogui as pg
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title('Facebook Sharing')
text = Label(window, text='Facebook Sharing Script', font="Source_Sans_Pro 20 bold")
text.pack()
frame = Frame(window)
frame.pack()

one = Frame(window)
one.pack( side = TOP )

frontframe = Frame(window)
frontframe.pack( side = TOP )


bottomframe = Frame(window)
bottomframe.pack( side = TOP )

lastframe = Frame(window)
lastframe.pack( side = TOP )

last = Frame(window)
last.pack( side = TOP )

Lable1 = Label(frame, text="Enter Your UserName!    ", font='Source_Sans_Pro 11')
Lable1.pack( side = LEFT)
user_name = Entry(frame, bd =5)
user_name.pack(side = RIGHT)

Lable2 = Label(frontframe, text="Enter Your Passowrd!     ", font='Source_Sans_Pro 11')
Lable2.pack( side = LEFT)
Password = Entry(frontframe, bd =5)
Password.pack(side = RIGHT)

Lable3 = Label(bottomframe, text="Enter Your Description!   ", font='Source_Sans_Pro 11')
Lable3.pack( side = LEFT)
description = Entry(bottomframe, bd =5)
description.pack(side = RIGHT)

Lable4 = Label(lastframe, text="Enter Your Keyword!       ", font='Source_Sans_Pro 11')
Lable4.pack( side = LEFT)
keyword = Entry(lastframe, bd =5)
keyword.pack(side = RIGHT)

Lable5 = Label(one, text="Enter Your Post Url!         ", font='Source_Sans_Pro 11')
Lable5.pack( side = LEFT)
post_url = Entry(one, bd =5)
post_url.pack(side = RIGHT)

Button_Start = Button(last, text="Start", fg="black", width=50, command=hi)
Button_Start.pack( side = BOTTOM)


pg.FAILSAFE = True


def hi():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    pg.click(1029, 109, duration=.30)
    driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(1)

print("Done")
window.mainloop()
```

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\All.py", line 55, in <module>
    Button_Start = Button(last, text="Start", fg="black", width=50, command=hi)
NameError: name 'hi' is not defined
```

Comment: you are assigning a function name that does not exists before this line - `Button_Start = Button(last, text="Start", fg="black", width=50, command=hi)`, move your function definition above this line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the `hi` function after assigning it to the button. Put the `hi` function before creating the button.

Do something like this:

```
def hi():
    ...
    ...

Button_Start = Button(last, text="Start", fg="black", width=50, command=hi)
Button_Start.pack( side = BOTTOM)
```